# Enlarging the number of visible communities?

Tags: discussion, support

I know that it may be a more general question, but TeX.StackExchange is my main community.

If I choose "Profile", I have on the left-hand side two frames: "Stats" and "Communities". However, only 5 (with the highest reputation?) of them are visible. Is there any possibility to set this value for a larger number?

**Edit:** My profile looks as in the picture:

[image]

Comment: You could exploit this bug/feature/whatever: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312317/limit-the-visible-number-of-hidden-communities-in-the-profile If you set the communities to private, you can all them at once.

Comment: Of course there is the 'View all' link above the Communities box, but you need to click it to see the communities so that is probably not what you want (but still an easy way if you are just interested in seeing this occasionally for yourself or for other users, instead of seeing it always when you visit your profile).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is too complicated for me. Could you explain it in details in an answer, please?